# How to open file in monaco editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

I am trying to setup mocano editor. All the examples I have seen so far show some source hard-coded into the index.js. What is the proper way to setup monaco editor to open/display files?

Answer (score 0):

Choose 1 specific file to fetch the content (AJAX maybe)
in the callback, using Monaco editor API setModel to update the content.